# codeigniter I have "302 Moved Temporarily" message when I post data

Tags: apache, codeigniter, post, input

I just moved my site to a live server which is apache. when I post a form to mycontroller/myfunction the server replies with "302 Moved Temporarily" message then it will redirect me to mycontroller/myfunction with all the post data lost.

Every think works fine in localhost.

Comment: whats your site URL ??

Comment: Found It. the problem was in the capital letter on the controller name

Comment: Check you .htaccess
Routing issue.